# analyzing pixels in a specific area of images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to calculate the height of an object from frames of a video. A method that I decided to use is to look at the position of the tip of the object(the tip of the object is white in color). I want to do this for thousands of frames. But since it takes a lot of time to make such analyzation over the whole image for all the frames I decided to look at a specific section of the image that I would input in. But I'm sort of lost as to how I can specify the section of the image look at and find the tip of the object with that range. here is a section of the code that measure the height.

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture("/Users/beadpile/Desktop/aman/bpile.mp4")   
_, frame = capture.read()
MovieBase = MovieName
angles=[]
y_base = 247
x_center = 569
x_edgeL = 51
x_edgeR = 1087
for i in range(0,1000):
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, i)
    _, frame = capture.read()
    white = [255,255,255]
    # Get X and Y coordinates of all white color pixels
    X,Y = np.where(np.all(frame==white,axis=2))
    XX=list(X)
    YY=list(Y)
    xpoints = np.array(X)
    ypoints = np.array(Y)
    test_list=list(zip(xpoints,ypoints))
    #get x,y coordinate of the white pixels found at the top     of the object
    subcoords = [(x, y) for x, y in test_list if y==min(YY)]
    s=[]
    for j in subcoords:
        s.append(j[0])
        #find average value of the x coordinate from subcoordds
        xax=sum(s)/len(subcoords)
        slope=(y_base-min(YY))/(xax-x_edgeL)
        #gets angle that extends from one point to the top of the object
        aangle=math.degrees(math.atan(slope))
        angles.append(aangle)
print(angles)
```

and here is a single frame [image]

Comment: You can use a mask to isolate the part in which you are interested